# TeXStudio very slow

Tags: texstudio

I found editing file with texstudo exceedingly slow (if I am editing the main document), not if I am editing an "input" file.
For the record, my disk is continuously being backed up with google drive. however, the problem persists if I deactivate synching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a large document and many input tex-files.

Texstudio was especially slow when I tried to comment lines out with shortcut ctrl+T.

Also deleting curly brackets was ridiculously slow.

It seemed that Texstudio loads all references in the background.

Disable following option:

Options -> Editor -> "Automatically load included files"

Solved my problem
PS: Worked on Ubuntu and Windows

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to disable that TeXstudio is interactively checking grammar, spelling, citing, syntax, etc.
I´ve done this also under options >> editor >> interactive ...